# Move semantics between base classes

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

We have these classes:

```
struct Intermediate : public std::array<double,3> {};

struct Vector3 : public Intermediate
{
   // ........more ctors.........

   // Modified move constructor (base class)
   Vector3(std::array<double,3> &&v) { ??????? }

   // ........more functionality...........
};
```

Is the "modified" move constructor act like original move constructor?

How can I implement the constructor?
Is there another way than std::array::swap?

Comment: When you `move` an array of `double` it will just do a copy anyway. `double` has no move semantics, only copy semantics

Comment: I know it's not what you asked, but do not inherit from `std::array`. Try sub-classing instead. As a bonus, if you subclass std::array, your (move) constructor becomes trivial.

Comment: You should **not** inherit from types that were not designed for inheritance (including `std::array<>` and most other containers). Other than that, there is nothing that can be *moved* from an `std::array<>` as data is held in place.

Comment: @utnapistim Guess what subclassing and inheritance have in common

Comment: @utnapistim Did you mean composition? Having a std::array as a member?

Comment: @utnapistim: What distinction do you make between "inherit from" and "subclass"?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
Vector3(std::array<double,3> &&v)
{ static_cast<std::array<double,3>&>(*this) = std::move(v); }
```

This move-assigns `v` to the base class of `this`

But that move constructor seems pretty pointless. When you `move` an array of `double` it will just do a copy anyway. `double` has no move semantics, only copy semantics, and `array<double,N>` contains the array directly within it, so cannot move it to another object.

Comment: @Xeo no need for `std::move(v)`?; darn that's a quick answer-edit :)

Comment: `std::array` is not a direct base class of Vector3, how you gonna do that then?  I wrote my answer that way for a reason (apparently the reason was that I actually read the question ;)

Comment: Hai hai, tunnel vision got the better of me. :) Sorry for that.